# How to forward logs and metrics to external databases on VMware VCH (A Custom Photon OS)

Tags: logging, vmware, fluentd

How can I forward the logs to FluentD and the metrics to InfluxDB on a VCH container in VMware VIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to simply get the metrics from vSphere into the TICK stack using the vSphere plugin in Telegraf. It's actually pretty straight forward.

See this page for a good tutorial, this guy did all the heavy lifting for you:
https://jorgedelacruz.uk/2018/10/01/looking-for-the-perfect-dashboard-influxdb-telegraf-and-grafana-part-xii-native-telegraf-plugin-for-vsphere/